# El usuario debe elegir un fichero .txt para validarlo

Tags: python

Tengo este codigo:

```
from funcions import*
import os
def menu():
  # Imprimeix el menú
  print("Menú")
  print("====")
  print("1. Validar Sudoku des de fitxer")
  print("2. Jugar partida de Sudoku")
  print("3. Sortir")
 
  # Demana l'opció escollida a l'usuari
  opcio = int(input("Introdueix la teva tria: "))
 
  # Retorna l'opció escollida
  return opcio
op=menu()

while op != 3:
    if op == 1:
        print("Introdueix el fitxer amb el sudoku que vols validar:")
        t = input()
        llegirSudoku(t)
        mostrarTaulell(t)
        validaSudoku(t)
    elif op ==2:
        t= (t)
    elif op ==4:
        print(prueba)
    else:
        print("Ho sento, opcio erronea")

    op = menu()
```

en la misma carpeta esta el fichero funcions.py desde donde importa las funciones de llegirSudoku, mostrarTaulell y validaSudoku. Estas 3 funciones funcionan no las inserto para no saturar la pregunta.
Esto pasa cuando ejecuto.
DEMO

```
>>> from projecte import *
Hola
Menú
====
1. Validar Sudoku des de fitxer
2. Jugar partida de Sudoku
3. Sortir
Introdueix la teva tria: 1
Introdueix el fitxer amb el sudoku que vols validar:
sudoku.txt
sudoku.txt
Aqui tens el teu Sudoku

  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
A s
B u
C d
D o
E k
F u
G .
H t
I x
Enhorabona, la fila conte tots els numeros requerits
La columna te numeros repetits
```

El problema que tengo es este que en vez de imprimirme el tablero con los numeros del sudoku me imprime la palabra que le inserto(se supone que el usuario pone el nombre del fichero)
El fichero en question:

```
647259381 
893761524 
521843976 
168594732 
734128695 
259637148 
982315467 
316472859 
475986213
```

Gracias de antemano
EDIT.
Aquí las funciones nombradas antes.

```
 def llegirSudoku(s):
        """
        Es comproba si el fitxer donat existeix, si existeix es es retorna una matriu amb la representació del Sudoku en format python.
        """
        try:
            fin = open(s, "r")
            text= fin.readlines()
            fin.close()
    
            r = []
            for linia in text:
                r.append(list(linia[:-1]))
            return r
        except IOError:
            print("Ho sento, el fitxer no existeix")
            return []
```

mostrarTaulell()

```
 def mostrarTaulell(h):
        """
        Donada una matriu mostra per pantalla la matriu resultant d'aplicar el format del proyecte
        >>> h = llegirSudoku("sudokuTaulell.txt")
        >>> mostrarTaulell(h)
        Aqui tens el teu Sudoku
        <BLANKLINE>
          1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
        A 5 3 X X 7 X X X X
        B 6 X X 1 9 5 X X X
        C X 9 8 X X X X 6 X
        D 8 X X X 6 X X X 3
        E 4 X X 8 X 3 X X 1
        F 7 X X X 2 X X X 6
        G X 6 X X X X 2 8 X
        H X X X 4 1 9 X X 5
        I X X X X 8 X X 7 9
        """
        print("Aqui tens el teu Sudoku")
        print()
        print("  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9")
        letras = "ABCDEFGHI"
        for pos in range(9):
            c = letras[pos]
            fila = h[pos]
            lista = [c] + fila
            s = " ".join(lista)
            print(s)
```

y valida sudoku:

```
def validaSudoku(t):
    for i in range(9):
        if not validaFila(t,i):
            return False
        if not validaColumna(t,i):
            return False
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            if not validaSubquadricula(t,i*3,j*3):
                return False
    print("Felicitats, el Sudoku es correcte.")
    print()
    return True
```

Que validaSudoku tiene dentro:

```
def validaFila(t,fila):
    numeros= (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
    if fila in numeros:
        validacio= set(t[fila])
        if len(t[fila]) != len(validacio):
            print("La fila te numeros repetits")
            return False
        print ("Enhorabona, la fila conte tots els numeros requerits")
        return True



def validaColumna(t, col):
    numbers= []
    for i in range(9):
        if t[i][col] in numbers or t[i][col] == "X":
            print("La columna te numeros repetits")
            return False
        numbers.append(t[i][col])
    print("Enhorabona, la columna conte tots els numeros requerits")
    return True

    
def validaSubquadricula(t, fil, col): 
    nums = set() 
    for i in range(3): 
        for j in range(3): 
            if t[fil + i][col + j]: 
                nums.add(t[fil + i][col + j])
    if len(nums) == 9:
        print("Aquesta subquadricula esta perfecte")
    else:
        print("Alguna cosa esta malamente en aquesta subquadricula")
    return len(nums) == 9

introducir el código aquí
```

Comment: Bueno, `t` es un string y lo estás usando para llamar a tres funciones distintas (no mostradas), una de las cuales espera una matriz como parámetro. Hay un error en la función que no muestras.

Comment: Mi intención es que t = fichero.txt, te inserto las otras tres funciones

Comment: @CandidMoe Debería estar actualizado

Comment: En ninguna parte ocupas el retorno de la función. Es tan básico.

Comment: Me imagina que todo lo que hago es super básico, a que función te refieres? LlegirSudoku?

Comment: Tienes que mirar cada función y preguntarte ¿qué retorna está función? y luego, donde la llamas, preguntarte ¿donde recibo el retorno de la función? ¿para qué me sirve, cómo lo ocupo?. Alguien te dara una respuesta en detalle.